# How to install a new OS to remove debian? Grub won't let me install from install dvd

Tags: windows, debian, uninstall

I am having trouble uninstalling Debian Linux. I recently got a cheap refurbished laptop and was planning on installing linux on it as I find I'm more productive with it. However after trying Debian, I realize I don't want to use this OS and would rather have a Windows / Elementary OS Dual Boot instead.

Now that I am trying to uninstall debian, on boot GRUB isn't displaying the DVD that has the windows or elemementary OS .iso file written to it to boot into or install.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Grub wouldn't show it. Find the boot device selection in the 'bios'(F12's the usual key for that) and select the DVD. If the DVD drive might be faulty, you might end up needing to get a liveusb to bootstrap the install from.